# How to pivot array build from REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pivot, flatten, unnest

I'm collecting url with query parameters in a BigQuery table. I want to parse these urls and then pivot the table. Input data and expected Output at the end.

I found two queries that I want to merge.

This one to pivot my parsed url:

```
select id, 
       max(case when test.name='a' then test.score end) as a,
       max(case when test.name='b' then test.score end) as b,
       max(case when test.name='c' then test.score end) as c
from 
(
select a.id, t
from `table` as a,
unnest(test) as t
)A group by id
```

then I have this query to parse the url:

```
WITH examples AS (
  SELECT 1   AS id, 
  '?foo=bar' AS query, 
  'simple'   AS description
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, '?foo=bar&bar=baz', 'multiple params'
  UNION ALL SELECT 3, '?foo[]=bar&foo[]=baz', 'arrays'
  UNION ALL SELECT 4, '', 'no query'
)
SELECT 
  id, 
  query,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(query,r'(?:\?|&)((?:[^=]+)=(?:[^&]*))') as params,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(query,r'(?:\?|&)(?:([^=]+)=(?:[^&]*))') as keys,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(query,r'(?:\?|&)(?:(?:[^=]+)=([^&]*))') as values,
  description
FROM examples
```

I'm not sure to explain my issues. But I think that is because when I'm splitting my query parameters as separate columns It doesn't match with the format of the first query where I need to `merge` the key and values under the same column so I can unnest them correctly.

**Input data:**

```
| id    | url                   |
|----   |--------------------   |
| 1     | url/?foo=aaa&bar=ccc  |
| 2     | url/?foo=bbb&bar=ccc  |
```

**expected output:**

```
| id    | foo  | bar |
|----   |----  |---- |
| 1     | aaa  | ccc |
| 2     | bbb  | ccc |
```

I have exactly the same number of parameters

Comment: please provide simplified input data and expected output - see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Use below

```
select id, 
  max(if(split(kv, '=')[offset(0)] = 'foo', split(kv, '=')[offset(1)], null)) as foo,
  max(if(split(kv, '=')[offset(0)] = 'bar', split(kv, '=')[offset(1)], null)) as bar
from `project.dataset.table` t, 
unnest(regexp_extract_all(url, r'[?&](\w+=\w+)')) kv
group by id
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]